# How can I handle subdomains with Flask, Cloudflare and Heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, subdomain, cloudflare

I bought a domain, let's say its "mydomain.org".
I connected that domain to Cloudflare and Heroku, and I can access my web app(site) on mydomain.org, handle the flask's route('/') requests.
But when I use, for example, route('/', subdomain="test") and try to return "This is a subdomain", it does nothing, or if it does, it redirects me to the simple route('/') (so basically without the subdomain).
I registered a subdomain on Heroku and created an alias for test.mydomain.org to point to the DNS that Heroku gave me, but I still get redirected to the main page, instead of getting simply the "This is a subdomain" message.
How could I make it work?

Comment: Has `app.config['SERVER_NAME']` been set to the base domain name so Flask knows what the subdomain is of?

Comment: No, because if I specify the server_name, it throws an error about setting a port number, but when I set the port number it throws an error about the server_name, because "UserWarning: Current server name 'mydomain.org:443' doesn't match configured server name 'mydomain.org'" (for example).

Comment: But sometimes it also says "[WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask app that routes based on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512698/flask-app-that-routes-based-on-subdomain)

Comment: When I do that, it works with server name "localhost:80", but when I try to pass my domain, eg. "mydomain.org:80" it returns this: https://pastebin.com/R5wN6ffc