# Flask - run subdomain on a new process

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I'm making a flask-app that needs to have several (about 5) subdomains:

- Each sub domain needs to be an app of it's own (using an app_factory)
- Each app needs to be created and added at runtime
- Each app MUST run on a different process (Singletons are involved)

I've swept through flask documentation but haven't found a solution that answers all my needs

Help please?

**EDIT:**
I'm essentially trying to find a way to run several apps running independantly on different processes, and serve them all through the same domain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask app that routes based on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512698/flask-app-that-routes-based-on-subdomain)

Comment: @noslenkwah not really.. please see the `edit` section in the original question

Comment: A reverse proxy (e.g. [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)) would do this easily for you.